# How to get a list of a values from a single ActiveRecord column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Code like this

```
my_id_results = MyTable.select("some_id").as_json
```

returns an array of hashes, each one of which contains both `id` and `some_`

```
[
    {id => nil, some_id => 1},
    {id => nil, some_id => 2},
    {id => nil, some_id => 3}
]
```

I can map this array to a list of ids like this

```
my_ids = []
my_id_results.each do |my_id_result|
  my_ids.push my_id_result['some_id']
end
```

For cases like this, where I'm looking for a list of values for a single column, is there a way to return the flat array directly from ActiveRecord?

Comment: `MyTable.pluck(:some_id)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, just use [`pluck`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck):

```
MyTable.pluck(:some_id)
#=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
MyTable.all.map &:some_id
```

would work as well.

For individual objects, I always use slice.

```
MyTable.first.slice :some_id
```

(Interestingly, this returns an ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.)

Comment: any reason to user `slice` instead of `pluck`?

Comment: @ab11 So, at the class
   (_MyTable_)
and relation
   (_MyTable.all_;
    _MyTable.where(archived: true)_)
levels you can use pluck (and it's less verbose than using map).
**At the object level**,
    (_MyTable.first_ |
    _MyTable.(color: 'red')[0]_)
pluck isn't a defined method, so you need to use slice, just as if you were slicing any hash.
    _h = {a: 1, b: 2};
    sliced = h.slice(:a)  # {a: 1}_

Comment: Correction:  _MyTable.where(color: 'red')[0]_  (i left out the "where")